# How can I configure a PCI compliant development environment

Tags: pci-dss

We need to be PCI compliant for some credit card processing we do.  How do people do this in other shops?

How do you secure your SVN?

How do you secure your build server?

How does code get migrated from the developers to production?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not to detract from the other answer, but the other thing you do is *limit the scope of compliance* by walling off the systems that see or touch card data from the rest of your IT infrastructure.  There should be no need for your SVN server or build server to comply with PCI requirements if there's no way for it to see cardholder data (of course, you must be able to show that this is actually a policy and not just an accident of how the network is set up)

Comment: It's not as simple as that. If your build server or SVN server can be compromised (just like kernel.org recently) then attackers can put malicious code into your systems, e.g. disable encryption, use a flawed key management algorithm, etc...

Comment: The point is well made, but as far as I understand it, that means I should have processes for checking the code that comes from my build server.  If I took that to mean my build server is within scope for my PCI assessment, then by the same token so would kernel.org be :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is all *the process* of PCI compliance.

Take a look at: http://www.keross.com/pci-dss-requirements-version-1.2.html

Typically, you'd hire an external security company who would help you through this process.

-- edit:

That link not lasting for 3 years, as requested I have googled "PCI DSS Compliance" to obtain: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/index.php

Comment: +1 for "hire an external security company". PCI compliance is not simple, and you'll probably need to be externally audited anyway if you want to handle credit card processing.

Comment: I'm afraid your link has rotted since 2010; could you update it?

Comment: @apsillers - This being posted so long ago I don't know what was there. I've added the first result for googling "PCI DSS compliance" though.